# Система координат в Java

Tags: java, графика, координаты

По умолчанию начало системы координат находится в верхнем левом углу. 
Каким образом я могу настроить так, чтобы начало системы координат находилось точно в центре моего созданного окна?

Comment: Простейший способ - написать метод, который транслирует ваши координаты (с воображаемым началом в центре окна) в координаты Java.

Comment: В Java нет такого понятия, как начало системы координат, и вопрос о том, где он находится, лишен смысла. Начало системы координат может быть у графических библиотек, которые могут использоваться. Но если вы хотите задать вопрос про графическую библиотеку, то следует как минимум указать, про какую из них вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речть про java swing, то можно сделать вот так:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // сдвинуть полотно в центр панели
    g.translate(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2); 
    // нарисовать все то что рисовали тут до этого
    paintStuff(g);
    // сдвинуть полотно обратно
    g.translate(-getWidth()/2, -getHeight()/2);
}
```

```js
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(new JPanel(){
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.translate(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        paintStuff(g);
        g.translate(-getWidth()/2, -getHeight()/2);
    }

    private void paintStuff(Graphics g) {
        for (double i = 0; i < Math.PI*2; i+= Math.PI/6){
            int x = (int) (Math.cos(i)*50);
            int y = (int) (Math.sin(i)*50);
            int s = 5;
            g.fillRect(x-s,y-s, s*2, s*2);
        }
    }
});
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(400, 400);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Так же, если лень считать как вернуть состояние обратно, допустим вы еще что-то поворачивали и потом опять двигали, то можно сделать так

```
super.paintComponent(g);
// создаем дочерний контекст
final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
try {
   // поворачиваем канву
   g2.rotate(0.4); 
   //двигаем её в центр
   g2.translate(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2); 
   // рисуем
   paintStuff(g2);
} finally {
   // уничтожаем контекст
   g.dispose(); 
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]